# Abort a running task in Celery within django

Tags: python, django, rabbitmq, celery, celery-task

I would like to be able to abort a task that is running from a Celery queue (using rabbitMQ).  I call the task using

```
task_id = AsyncBoot.apply_async(args=[name], name=name, connect_timeout=3)
```

where AsyncBoot is a defined task.

I can get the task ID (assuming that is the long string that `apply_async` returns) and store it in a database but I'm unsure how to call an abort method.  I see how to make methods abortable with the Abortable tasks class but if I only have the task-id string, how do I call .abort() on the task? Thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`apply_async` returns an `AsyncResult` instance, or in this case an `AbortableAsyncResult`. Save the `task_id` and use that to instantiate a new `AbortableAsyncResult` later, making sure you supply the backend optional argument if you're not using the `default_backend`.

```
abortable_async_result = AsyncBoot.apply_async(args=[name], name=name, connect_timeout=3)
myTaskId = abortable_async_result.task_id
```

Later:

```
abortable_async_result = AbortableAsyncResult(myTaskId)
abortable_async_result.abort()
```

Comment: It is worth noting that the celery docs say: "this class will only work with the database backends." http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/reference/celery.contrib.abortable.html?highlight=abort#celery.contrib.abortable

Answer (score 4):

Did you see the reference documentation?
http://celeryq.org/docs/reference/celery.contrib.abortable.html

To abort the task use `result.abort()`:

```
>>> result = AsyncBoot.apply_async(...)
>>> result.abort()
```

Comment: But how do I get result object at a later date if all I have is the task_id? I'm trying to abort the task when I no longer have access to the result object.  I need someway to pull it from the database.

Comment: Pickle the result object in the database then

Comment: `mytask.AsyncResult(task_id)` or `from celery.result import AsyncResult; AsyncResult(task_id)`.